# Querying Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields

I've been back and forth with this and not able to get my [Advanced Custom Field query working](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/).

According to the documentation in the link above, this is what my array should look like:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'location',
    'meta_value' => 'Melbourne'
);
```

Below is my array. The problem is clearly in the meta_key and meta_value I am trying to query. Without the meta_key and meta_value, all the Products are being returned as expected. I have been into the database to make sure I have the right values so this looks correct to me. Is there something that stand out to anyone I might be missing? Thanks

```
        <section class="entry-content clearfix search-results sectiondrop" itemprop="articleBody">
            <h3>Search Results</h3>
            <?php 
                $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'Product', 
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                    'orderby' => 'title', 
                    'order' => 'ASC', 
                    'meta_key' => 'product_type',
                    'meta_value' => 'Paper'
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
                <ul>
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <li>
                            <strong><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php the_field('product_type'); ?></strong><br>
                            <?php the_field('product_description'); ?><br><br>
                        </li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </section>
```

**EDIT:**

This is what my array looks like now:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'product_type'
           )
        )

);
```

Just the "key" alone does the trick right, but as soon as I add the "value" the search does not return any results. And I know that the value should be "Paper" in this case.

**EDIT**

I've looked again at the DB, the product from wp_posts through to wp_postmeta and filtered meta_value by "Paper" and they all return the following a:1:{i:0;s:9:"Paper";} where I supposedly should have just "Paper"

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `meta_query` in your `$args`. You are far more flexible this way. For the full reference of the possibilities check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'Product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'product_type',
           'value' => 'Paper',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Fischi. I had read through the Codex and tried this option. Let me give it another spin and see what comes of it.

Comment: I've tried your solution Fischi and it didn't work. I'm wondering if I am using the right name and value? It's got to be this but looking at the DB, some of the meta_key's for ACF starts with an underscore...could that be the problem?

Comment: Yeah, that could be the problem. You have to enter the exact key as it is in your database.

Comment: nope, the underscores aren't the problem. AFAIK, ACF names starting with an underscore refer to the unique id of that field.

Comment: This is when I take a look at the generated SQL query to see what is going on. `var_dump( $loop->request );`

Comment: @RRikesh I've added another EDIT above..thanks for all the responses so far. I will have a look at the var_dump( $loop->request ); option next.

Comment: @fischi if I use 'compare' => 'LIKE', then I get results. I hope this is good enough to use. :)